# Wordpress error - Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page. After migrating website from one domain to another

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I keep seeing the error - Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page. When trying to login to the website at the new hosting location and new domain.

What I have tried to far:

- logged into PHP my admin created a new user in the wp_users table
  used md5() to set the password
- went into the wp_usermeta and added wp_capabilities
  a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
- added wp_user_level 10 to wp_usermeta table
- created a new fresh .htaccess file
- went into the wp_options table and updated template, stylesheet & active_plugins to use a twentyseventeen theme and plugins a:0:{}
- I enabled WP_debug and only got the following errors:

```
[21-Mar-2019 23:22:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant is_transparent - assumed 'is_transparent' in /home/yarrasol/public_html/wp-content/themes/okab/framework/functions/admin/customizer/css-var/css_navbar.php on line 3
[21-Mar-2019 23:22:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dima_body_background_image_repeat in /home/yarrasol/public_html/wp-content/themes/okab/framework/functions/admin/customizer/css-var/css_page.php on line 7
[21-Mar-2019 23:22:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dima_body_background_image_position in /home/yarrasol/public_html/wp-content/themes/okab/framework/functions/admin/customizer/css-var/css_page.php on line 8
[21-Mar-2019 23:22:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dima_body_background_image_size in /home/yarrasol/public_html/wp-content/themes/okab/framework/functions/admin/customizer/css-var/css_page.php on line 9
[21-Mar-2019 23:22:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dima_body_background_image_attachment in /home/yarrasol/public_html/wp-content/themes/okab/framework/functions/admin/customizer/css-var/css_page.php on line 10
```

There is more errors - but wasn't able to post them without getting flagged as spam.

Sorry for the long post, just trying to be as descriptive as possible thank you all in advance.

Comment: i really hope wordpress is not still using md5 for password storage. is this every page of the site or your admin end?

Comment: looks like your okab theme is buggy, missing dependencies, or incompatible with your wordpress version.

Comment: Hi Danblack and tim, thank you both for your comments. I managed to figure out the issue. Due to the database tables in the original hosting server having a different prefix, I should have updated the wp-config.php file to the updated prefix. However I updated all the database tables to match the prefix shown in the config file, I noticed this issue as I dropped the wp_options table and loaded one int from a different wp install and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

thank you your comments. I managed to figure out the issue. Due to the database tables in the original hosting server having a different prefix, I should have updated the wp-config.php file to the updated prefix. However I updated all the database tables to match the prefix shown in the config file, I noticed this issue as I dropped the wp_options table and loaded one in from a different wp install and it worked.